# UNet pytorch implementation is too slow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a tensorflow based simple UNet model used for optimization program. The program is something like an “untrained” neural net in the sense that once I load input data (experimental low res images) in variable “input_frames”, I don’t have to load any other data as I’m passing the same frames as input in each epoch. Once UNet generates some image, that image is used to generate low res images using physics based model say convolution with known experimental point spread function and uses the loss between “input_frames” and simulated low res images from UNet generated image is optimized.I want to implement it in pytorch so I have written the equivalent version of it. Given below are the two implementations:

Tensorflow implmentation -

```
k_size = 3

def u_net():
    
    inputs = Input((cropsize,cropsize,frames))
    block1 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(inputs)
    
    block2 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block1)
    block2 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block2)
    down1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(block2)
    
    block3 = Conv2D(64, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(down1)
    block3 = Conv2D(64, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block3)
    down2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(block3)
    
    block4 = Conv2D(128, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(down2)
    block4 = Conv2D(128, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block4)
    down3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(block4)
    
    block5 = Conv2D(256, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(down3)
    block5 = Conv2D(256, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block5)
    
    up1 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(block5)
    cat1 = concatenate([block4,up1])
    block6 = Conv2D(128, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(cat1)
    block6 = Conv2D(128, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block6)
    
    up2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(block6)
    cat2 = concatenate([block3,up2])
    block7 = Conv2D(64, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(cat2)
    block7 = Conv2D(64, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block7)
    
    up3 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(block7)
    cat3 = concatenate([block2,up3])
    block8 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(cat3)
    block8 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block8)
    block9 = Conv2D(32, (k_size, k_size), padding="same", activation = 'relu')(block8)
    output = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding="same")(block9)
    output = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=1.0)(output)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[output])
    
    return model
```

and Pytorch version

```
# full assembly of the sub-parts to form the complete net
from unet_parts import *


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.inc = inconv(n_channels, 32)
        self.down1 = down(32, 64)
        self.down2 = down(64, 128)
        self.down3 = down(128, 256)
        # remember if you are using bilinear interpolation or convtranspose2d for upsampling
        # when using bilinear interpolation, in channels for up1 is 256+128
        # when using convtranspose2d, in channels for up1 is 256, up2 is 128
        self.up1 = up(384, 128)
        self.up2 = up(192, 64)
        self.up3 = up(96, 32)

        self.outc4 = outconvpadded(32, out_ch=32)
        self.outc5 = outconv(32, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.inc(x)
        x2 = self.down1(x1)
        x3 = self.down2(x2)
        x4 = self.down3(x3)
        x = self.up1(x4, x3)
        x = self.up2(x, x2)
        x = self.up3(x, x1)
        x = self.outc4(x)
        x = self.outc5(x)
        return x
```

where its sub parts are defined as -

```
# sub-parts of the U-Net model

import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class double_conv(nn.Module):
    '''(conv => BN => ReLU) * 2'''
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(double_conv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(out_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class triple_conv(nn.Module):
    '''(conv => BN => ReLU) * 2'''
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(triple_conv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(out_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(out_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x

class inconv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(inconv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = triple_conv(in_ch, out_ch)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class down(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(down, self).__init__()
        self.mpconv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            double_conv(in_ch, out_ch)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.mpconv(x)
        return x


class up(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch, bilinear=True):
        super(up, self).__init__()

        #  if your machine do not have enough memory to handle all those weights
        #  bilinear interpolation could be used to do the upsampling.
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_ch, out_ch, 2, stride=2)

        self.conv = double_conv(in_ch, out_ch)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class outconvpadded(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(outconvpadded, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class outconv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(outconv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x
```

I have used Bilinear upsampling in place of ConvTranspose2d because tensorflow code had the same.

I plan to use custom loss function for my problem. But for basic ssim loss, tensorflow code runs way faster than pytorch (2 min vs 15 min approximately). Earlier I was using ConvTranspose2d, but i noticed that tensorflow is using bilinear upsampling, i changed that in my pytorch version. Also i had to modify input channels in up part of UNet. I’ve also tried not using Batch Norm as tensorflow code isn’t using it, but it didn’t solve the problem. I’ve read how to optimize pytorch guide and am setting grads to zero as told in the guide. I’ve implemented the model exactly same as tensorflow, then why am i noticing so much time difference ? Obviously I’m wrong somewhere but i fail to notice. Please help me. Any help would be appreciated. I’ve tried this like for over a month but to no avail.

Also I'm providing the setting up of two models in case I'm missing something there.

Tensorflow -

```
learning_rate = 0.001

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    learning_rate,
    decay_steps=50,
    decay_rate=0.90,
    staircase=True)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule)
batch_size = 1
eps = 400
l = Physics_Loss

def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    def lr(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32)
    return lr

lr_metric=get_lr_metric(opt)

model.compile(loss=l, optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy',lr_metric],run_eagerly=True)
model_history = model.fit(x=single_input,y=single_input,epochs=eps,batch_size=batch_size)
```

Pytorch  -

```
model = UNet(n_channels=9, n_classes=1)
print("{} parameters in total".format(sum(x.numel() for x in model.parameters())))
learning_rate = 0.001

cuda=torch.device('cuda:0')
model=model.to(cuda)

# Create the Adam optimizer with the initial learning rate
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Create an ExponentialLR scheduler to decay the learning rate
lr_schedule = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=50, gamma=0.90)

# Set batch size and number of epochs
batch_size = 1
epochs = 50

l = Physics_loss
train_losses=[]

for epoch in range(epochs):
    running_loss=0.0
    inputs=input_frames
     # zero the parameter gradients
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.grad=None
    outputs=model(inputs) # forward pass
    loss=l(inputs,outputs)
    loss.backward() #backpropagate the loss
    optimizer.step() # update the weights
    lr_schedule.step() # update the learning rate
    running_loss+=loss
    train_loss=running_loss/1
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    #print average training loss for the epoch
    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch+1, train_loss))
```

I've tried deploying the model using Lightning, but same issue, it's incredibly slow while keras is amzingly fast. Please help, I couldn't figure out the issue.

physics_loss for tensorflow -

```
def Physics_Loss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    loss = 0
    y_pred = tf.transpose(y_pred,(3,1,2,0))
    y_true = tf.transpose(y_true,(3,1,2,0))
    
    for i in range(0,(batch_size)):
        
        pred = y_pred[:,:,:,i-1]
        pred = tf.expand_dims(pred,3)
        # multiply predicted object by illumination patterns
        prod = tf.math.multiply(pred,patterns)
        # convolve with PSF
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(prod,psf,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME',data_format='NHWC')    
        conv = tf.math.divide(tf.math.subtract(conv,tf.reduce_min(conv)),tf.math.subtract(tf.reduce_max(conv),tf.reduce_min(conv)))
       
        true = y_true[:,:,:,i-1]
        true = tf.expand_dims(true,3)
        pl_flag=1
        pl_loss=0
        im_loss = SSIM_Loss(conv,true)
        if pl_flag:
            pl_loss=perceptual_loss(conv,true)  
            loss = loss + 0.5*pl_loss + 0.5*im_loss
        else:
            loss = loss + im_loss
        print("im_loss",im_loss)
        print("pl_loss",pl_loss)
            
    return loss
```

for pytorch -

```
def Physics_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss=torch.tensor(0.0,dtype=torch.float64).to(cuda)
    # y_pred=torch.cat([y_pred]*frames,dim=1)
    # print("y_pred shape:",y_pred.shape)
    # print("y_true shape:",y_true.shape)
    # print("patterns shape:",patterns.shape)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        prod=y_pred*patterns
        # print("prod shape:",prod.shape)
        conv=torch.zeros_like(prod)
        # print("conv type",conv.dtype)
        padding = (psf.shape[-2] - 1) // 2
        for j in range(frames):
            single_image=prod[:,j:j+1,:,:]
            # print("single image type: ",single_image.dtype)
            # print("psf type: ",psf.dtype)
            convolved_image=f.conv2d(single_image,psf,stride=1,padding=padding)
            # print("convolved image shape:",convolved_image.shape)
            conv[:,j:j+1,:,:]=convolved_image
        conv=(conv-torch.min(conv))/(torch.max(conv)-torch.min(conv))
        # print("conv shape:",conv.shape)
        true=y_true
        individual_losses=torch.zeros(frames)
        # finding perceptual loss for each frame
        for j in range(frames):
            y_true_frame=y_true[:,j:j+1,:,:]
            y_pred_frame=conv[:,j:j+1,:,:]
            y_true_rgb=torch.cat([y_true_frame]*3,dim=1)
            y_pred_rgb=torch.cat([y_pred_frame]*3,dim=1)
            # print("y_pred_rgb shape:",y_true_rgb.shape)
            # print("y_true_rgb shape:",y_pred_rgb.shape)
            pl_j_loss=perceptual_loss(y_true_rgb,y_pred_rgb)
            # torch.cuda.empty_cache()
            individual_losses[j]=pl_j_loss
        normalized_losses=individual_losses/frames
        final_pl=torch.sum(normalized_losses)
        print("final_pl:",final_pl)

        #total loss
        im_loss=0.6*SSIM_Loss(conv,true)+0.4*final_pl
        loss+=im_loss
        print("total_loss: ",loss)
        
    return loss
```

EDIT: As suggested by @rr_goyal, I have modified the pytorch model and now they are the same models, but the problem of pytorch being too slow still remains.

EDIT : Added physics_loss definitions

EDIT : https://github.com/bfaast/untrained_pinn

pinn_demo_sim.ipynb is tensorflow part.

pinn_custom_loss_torch.ipynb is pytorch part.

Comment: I don't think both of your versions are "equivalent"; there is a difference between the number of conv2D, batchNorm, ReLU layers in both models. The no. of channels of the Conv2D layers seems higher in pytorch than in keras. This MIGHT be the reason.

Comment: Additionally to what rr_goyal said, you seem to zero the parameters in a inefficient way. Instead of your for loop over `model.parameters()`, try `optimizer.zero_grad()`. You can also look into profiling to see if ou find a bottleneck in the pytorch version. Do you also do `.to(cuda)` on your data? In your epoch loop you does not, but maybe ealier. Can't tell from your example.

Comment: Also, if you use PyTorch 2.x or >=1.7, and you use a Nvidia Ampere GPU (e.g. A100 or RTX 3000 series, google for full list), you can enable TensorFloat-32 computations, which are a lot faster and by default disabled by Pytorch and enabled by TensorFlow. Enable with `torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True`. Brought ~7x speed and 2x error on example in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#tensorfloat-32-tf32-on-ampere-devices

Comment: @rr_goyal I see. Tensorflow has seven conv layers in encoding part while pytorch version has 8 layers. I see, in order to correct it, first inconv block should have only one cov layer without max pool. I see. Thanks. I'll check it and let you know if it works. Also if you could add it as answer so that I can accept it if it works. Many thanks.

Comment: @mhenning Initially i was using optimizer.zero_grad(), but in a pytorch performance guide I saw that recommended like this. I'll check the context and let you know. Also I'm on GTX 1650 Ti do you think your latter recommendation applies in my case ?Thanks.

Comment: No, the 1650 TI has no Tensor Cores, so the `allow_tf32` does not matter. On the recommendation for the optimizer and `None`, I found this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html. But it sounds like pitfalls for advaced usage, so most likely it does not matter. Out of interest, how much slower/faster is the difference? What are the timings?

Comment: @AnkurSingh I will add that as an answer.

Comment: @mhenning the difference is like 5-6 times. But as rr_goyal pointed out, models seem to be different, so will have to modify and then check.

Comment: @rr_goyal I just noticed that it's actually the opposite. Pytorch version has less convolution layers as compared to Tensorflow version. Since incov and down involves two conv layers, and outconv has one layer. So one inconv+three down and three up is 14 layers and one conv for outconv. While tensorflow has 17 conv layers. So I think tensorflow has more layers.

Comment: @rr_goyal I have corrected the pytorch model as suggested but the problem persists.

Comment: Again, do you load the data into the GPU? You do `model=model.to(cuda)`, but you have to do the same with the training data. Either as a whole before the training or batch-wise if you iterate over it. Also, it seems you do `MaxPoo2D` first in the `down` class for Pytorch while it comes after the `Conv2D` layers in TF. (not that it should affect performance that much)

Comment: @mhenning Yes, i have moved the input data to gpu. also even though looks like maxpool is first then conv layers but if you compared with the tf, then it is correct in the sense that each maxpool is applied on previous block and then there  are conv layers.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem and got into some errors. What is your version of TF/Torch/CUDA and what is `Physics_Loss`? For TF 2.13 it tells me that `Adam` has to attribute `_decayed_lr`. In the future, a fully reproducible, minimal example code will help from the start.

Comment: I've prepared 2 colabs with slightly modified code from you (made it executable for me) TF: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xHa9nyEAPF1y7qU52q9biYeSISHeyoP9, PyTorch: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TV7tsYtsO-DM6ojNxbTACR6aEgHOTEP2. For TF, I got 2 runs, one with `batch size` 1, and one with `batch_size` 50 (all images), as you don't work with batch sizes in PyTorch (all images are worked on at once). As you can see, the training time is (almost) the same for PyTorch and TF with the same batch size (~17-18s).

Comment: @mhenning that you so much for the time invested. I'll check out both versions and let you know what issues i have. Love it !

Comment: @mhenning tf is 2.10, pytorch is latest (2.x), cuda 11.2 for tf, cuda 11.7 for pytorch. Physics_loss is a custom function that I implemented. I'll add it in the question.

Comment: There are missing variable declarations for the loss (like `patterns`, `frames`, `perceptual_loss`). Please see the notebooks for the variables. Please include fully working code with all variables and imports in your question.

Comment: @mhenning , i have added GitHub repo containing all dependent images and codes. Please have a look

Comment: I'm afraid that's a bit too much code to work through. My test showed that it is not the model which slowed it down. Try to replace some parts of your pipeline with dummy parts and test when it's getting slow. Replace your images with dummy data (as with the `np.random.rand()` data in my notebook), or replace your loss function with a cross entropy loss from TF/PyTorch. This should show you the bottleneck in your functions.

Comment: A first hint for the pytorch version would be to look at the `Physics_loss` function. Make sure everything is on the same device. E.g. initiate cuda tensors with `torch.zeros_like(prod, device=cuda)`. The `.to` command copies the tensor after creation. If there are some tensors on cpu and some on gpu and you do computations with both, this could lead to serious waiting times. I think you can also vectorize the for loop over the `batch_size` tomake it faster. Edit: Also I'm not sure hy you set `float64` as the default dtype, it slowes computation down while not bringing much more accuracy.